What is the best approach to have dynamic tabs with dynamic content in Blazor?
Working on a Blazor application, I am wondering what would be the best approach to implement dynamic tabs with dynamic content. I have searched extensively but did not arrive to a satifying conclusion and now am looking for some advice. I hope it is OK to post this here, if not, I'll happily remove the question.
My use case in a nutshell:

The app is used to visualize logging data from remote systems (timeseries based data, stored in a database)
The user must be able open and close various tabs for each connected system; eg. to visualize raw data of type 1, visualize raw data of type 2, visualize processed data, etc. So, tabs can have a variety of different Components in them, based on what the user chose to access.
It should be possible to open the same type of tab multiple times, both for different systems as well as for the same system, ie. to have diferent dates 'open' for a single system.
Switching between tabs should be possible without loosing state (or at least it should appear like this)

Currently, I have a frontend app written in WPF. It uses AvalonDock for the above requirements. I am aware I cannot (and probably should not want to) replicate AvalonDock in Blazor, but am hoping to at least be able to have a flexible "tabbed" approach. This looks liek this, to get an idea of the current goal:

So far I see two possible approaches:

Have a list of states for open tabs, that are used to serve content via a single Component. I could use OnParametersSet to set the tab id and apply the state, ie. using DynamicComponent or some kind of branching logic. This would kind of mimmick DataTemplate from WPF to choose the right way to display the data. It seems kind of complex to store the complete needed state by hand, but maybe it is the way to go?
Somehow instantiate and store Components as is proposed here. Though I have doubts if that would really allow me to have a disctinct and persistent state per instantiated Component. This would seem like an easier approach, since the state is simply stored with the Component.

Does anyone have some advice here? I am rather new to Blazor and kind of stuck as to how to apporach this problem. Especially the combination of a dynamic number of tabs, with varying/dynamic content based on what the user chooses, seems to be hard to find the best approach for.
Any help appreciated!

Option 2 is NO, so it's option 1.
You want to display a list of tabs with state.  So think Dictionary<Type, Object> where Type is the type of the top level component and Object is the state object for each specific Type. You'll need to cast it in the specific component.
For example if you are displaying a list it would contain a ListState instance with the current page, the filter and the sort order.
You need to decide how you persist the dictionary.  In a Scoped service if only for the SPA scope, or in protected browser storage if you want to persist across SPA sessions.
Once you have the list you can build the tabs containing a DynamicComponent based on the dictionary entry.  The Type defines the component type to create and the Object, the state data to pass as a parameter.

Thank you for this reply, it makes things more clear. And thank you for replaying so fast it got through before the question was closed (-:
Making the combination between Type and DynamicComponent is helpful, that gets me on the right track. If there are two tabs in this case, with the same Type, will this still work? Will there be two components initiated, or will it work cause the state object gets swapped? (Also out of curiosity)

The reason 2 is NO is because the Renderer creates and disposes Components based on the page content.  You don't.  In this case it will create instances of Type for each dynamic component definition and apply the relevant state object instance from dictionary.

This works well. I implemented something along theses lines; the state is stored away from the components, and applied to a DynamicComponent inside a tab item. This results in the components being loaded anew each time the user switched tabs, and then the saved state is used to instantiate the tab, making it appear as if it was there all along. I guess this is the way it is supposed to work in Blazor?

Yeah, this question is going to get closed pretty fast, as you haven't provided any code of your own about which you're asking a specific and answerable question.  In a nutshell, you're saying, "I want tabs in Blazor, how do I do that?"  ChatGPT or a Google search would be a better place to start.
Since your question is general, I will not give you code but rather general advice:

Don't think "I will make some tabs, and figure out how to persist the data in them all and switch among them"  Think, "I will have a list of C# data objects, a collection of buttons to choose among them, and a tab component to express just one."  A common Parent object will hold that data, so you don't need to worry about persisting anything, unless you want the data to persist even if the page is closed.
The Parent object will have a List<TabDataItem> Items; and a TabDataItem SelectedItem.
The Parent will do a foreach (var item in Items) and display a button or clickable div for each item.
In the foreach, if item == SelectedItem, you will highlight the button with additional CSS.
You will then have a <TabDisplayer Item=SelectedItem /> which will display the selected data however you want.
Adding or removing tabs is simple: you just do Items.Add(newItem); or Items.Remove(clickedItem);


Thank you for this reply, even if I did not provide code. I'll try to create a minimal example.

Actually I have tried something along the lines you describe. It is more or less the first option I named in my (apperently too vague) question. Basically, in order to have dynamic content on a per-tab basis, I'll have to make branching logic in the TabDisplayer component. And then if the tab gets switched, update the component. Thanks for you insight.

Now it's closed (-: The thing I don't really get about stackoverflow is why it is not OK to ask a question like this. Making an example for this would involve a lot of lines of code. Where else to ask this kind of thing, if the likes of g00gle don't provide any meaningful data?

Most of my questions get shot down for the same reason, as if it were just a matter of code, I would already have done it myself.  I'll ask things like "What are the best practices for ensuring thread safety when using multiple timers" or whatever-- how do you make code about that?  But it is what it is.

re: TabDisplayer in complex cases, for me this is often nothing BUT branching logic, with each type inheriting from TabDataItem and inheriting a unique Interface, so:  @if (TabData is TaxScheduleData TSD) { <TaxScheduleDisplay Data=TSD> } etc.
